# Error when assign value for matrix in iml procedure

Tags: sas

I simply want to assign a row of matrix by a vector in iml procedure, but it returns error. The code is as follow, how can I fixed it?

```
 proc iml;
 za=repeat(0,4,3);
 a=123;
 b=321;
 c=222;
 za[1,]={a,b,c};
 run;
 print(za);
 proc print;run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. {x, y, z} is a column vector. {x y z} is a row vector. Which means you attempt to insert a column in a row. Also, the syntax is a bit off.

Using your own code, you can do this.

```
proc iml;
 za=repeat(0,4,3);
 a=123;
 b=321;
 c=222;
 za[1,] = a || b || c;
 print(za);
quit;
```

A simpler way would be

```
proc iml;
   za = j(4, 3, 0);
   v = {123 321 222};
   za[1, ] = v;
   print za;
quit;
```